# How to plot theoretical Pareto distribution in R?

Tags: r, math, plot, distribution

I need to plot theoretical Pareto distribution in R.

I want this as a line - not points and not polylines.

My distribution function is 1−(1/x)^2.

I plotted empirical distribution of my sample and also theoretical distribution at one graph:

```
ecdf(b2)
plot(ecdf(b2))
lines(x, (1-(1/x)^2), col = "red", lwd = 2, xlab = "", ylab = "")
```

But I got:

[image]

You can see that red line is not continuous, it's something like polyline. Is it possible to get the continuous red line?

Do you have any advices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `curve()` instead.

```
library(EnvStats)
set.seed(8675309)
# You did not supply the contents of b2 so I generated some
b2 <- rpareto(100, 1, 2)
plot(ecdf(b2))
ppareto <- function(x) 1−(1/x)^2
curve(ppareto, col = "red", add = TRUE)
```

[image]